# Create feature class with ArcObjects in SDE geodatabase returns No editable Layer

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase

I want To create Feature Class in an enterprise geodatabase with ArcObjects. This is a small part of our plugin. In our case, we want to create a Feature Class in the database Identical to the layer that is in TOC. It creates that successfully, but when we add it to the TOC and want to edit it, ArcMap returns the message `This data is not editable`. The user has full permission.

It is possible to create Feature Class manually in geodatabase With a database Connection in the Catalog tree; It was successfully created and it is editable and I can Register it as versioned. But When I try to create a feature Class with Arcobjects it returns `No editable Layer` and I can't edit the feature Class.

SQL Server in use: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Edition (64-bit) ,  version of  ArcGIS in use: 10.2.2, the license level of ArcGIS: Advanced (ArcInfo) Concurrent Use.

This is our code:

```c#
        Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.SqlWorkspaceFactory");
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
        IPropertySet connectionProps = new PropertySetClass();
        connectionProps.SetProperty("SERVER", "gSERVER");
        connectionProps.SetProperty("INSTANCE", "sde:sqlserver:gSERVER-pc");
        connectionProps.SetProperty("DATABASE", "Ga");
        connectionProps.SetProperty("DBCLIENT", "SQLServer");
        connectionProps.SetProperty("SERVERINSTANCE", "gSERVER-pc\\sqlraSERVER"); 
        connectionProps.SetProperty("AUTHENTICATION_MODE", "OSA");
        IFeatureWorkspace workspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspaceFactory.Open(connectionProps, 0);
        IMxDocument mxd = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
        IMap map = mxd.FocusMap;
        ILayer layer = map.Layer[0] as ILayer;
        IFeatureLayer featurlayer = layer as IFeatureLayer;
        IFeatureClass fc = featurlayer.FeatureClass;
        IWorkspace wrk = workspace as IWorkspace;
        IFields fields = featurlayer.FeatureClass.Fields;
        IFeatureWorkspace hhj = workspace as IFeatureWorkspace;

        IFeatureClass outputFeatClass = hhj.CreateFeatureClass(featurlayer.Name, fields, featurlayer.FeatureClass.CLSID, null, featurlayer.FeatureClass.FeatureType, "SHAPE", "");
```

Comment: Please do not capitalize every other word. It Makes Reading More Difficult. Keep in mind that SDE does not exist, especially from ArcObjects. Please [Edit] the question to specify the *exact* SQL Server in use, the exact version of 10.2.x ArcGIS in use, and the license level of ArcGIS in your application.

Comment: SQL Server in use: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Edition (64-bit) ,  version of  ArcGIS in use: 10.2.2, the license level of ArcGIS: Advanced (ArcInfo) Concurrent Use.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information. I wonder if Express 2008 is even supported at 10.2.2. "Enterprise" geodatabases in Express are anything but enterprise-ready.

Comment: I have edited the question. It is possible to create Feature Class manually in geodatabase With database Connection in Catalog tree; It successfully created and it is editable and i can Register it as versioned . But When i try to create feature Class with Arcobjects it returns No editable Layer and i cant edit feature Class.(Above Code)

Comment: Again, put these details **in the question**. You should be able to delete your comments without losing any information.

Comment: @arkadas Unless you're not providing your entire code, seems like you're missing some FC info including declaring an OID field. Here are some old but useful samples you can lean on ( I can't find a link to the 10.x samples sorry): http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/arcobjects/esriGeodatabase/IFeatureWorkspace.CreateFeatureClass_Example.htm

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong Workspace Factory. Use "SDEWorkspaceFactory" instead of "SqlWorkspaceFactory"